# How to prevent layout from overlapping with iOS status bar IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework

A picture worth 1k words:

[image]

You can see the black icons of battery/wifi are overlapped with the white burger menu.

My code is the following:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-menu-toggle></ion-menu-toggle>
    <h1> Some text><h1>
</ion-header
```

I would to make changes that don't make troubles with android layout, as the current layout with android is a success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use env() to get the safe-area-inset-top and set a padding or margin equal to it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env().

Ionic also defines them as global css variables that you can use instead: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced#global-variables